# Magento adding product images using API fails

Tags: api, magento, soap

I'm using the 'catalogProductAttributeMediaCreate' V2 SOAP service call to create images for products. This worked fine for months but has been failing since a couple of days.
The API call itself returns a **successful** action. No exception is thrown by Magento and the call returns an image id in the form of a string like '/f/e/ferrari-f12-berlinetta-wallpapers-pictures-backgrounds.jpg_4.jpg'.
But when I check the magento admin backend, no images are shown. When I check the table in mysql I notice that magento hasn't created a record for it. Even though the API call returns a success.
Adding images through the admin backend manually works fine. I've re-installed the entire magento site. But the fauls persists.
When I use the API to remove the image it returns an exception, telling me that the image '/f/e/ferrari-f12-berlinetta-wallpapers-pictures-backgrounds.jpg_4.jpg' does not exist. Which makes sense as it's not present in the database.

So, why does the API returns a successful action and an image ID, when it obviously fails. And where do I start to troubleshoot?